# Python interpreter format issue

Tags: python

Interpreter became weird. As showed below, after printing out `a`, I needed to press another enter to start next typing.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
>>> 1        
>>>
```

What I expected is

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
    1
>>>
```

Which is after printing out `a`, I should be able to type instead of pressing another enter to start. I am running Python 3.5 on Mac.

Comment: Did you try exiting and restarting the interpreter?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, it not only happened in one case. It's normal behaviour in my interpreter.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Actually, the problem happened with the macport version of Python, in both 2.7 and 3.5. The official mac python3.5 works well.